# There are two rocks in front of your hourse. True or false: There is one rock in front of your house

Tags: logic, terminology

I say true because there is indeed one rock in front of your house (it is also reasonable to say that there are two rocks). However, my teacher is claiming that the statement is false and sees the statement as "There is only one rock in front of your house." Who is right? Is there a certain theorem or definition that settles this debate?

Sidenote: I notice this is similar to the question "How many months have 28 days", the answer being 12.

Comment: This isn't a math question as much as it is a question about word use.  I think most people would interpret this use of "one rock" to mean "at least one rock" but of course it might also mean "exactly one rock".  It's ambiguous so, if it matters, the writer should clarify which is intended.

Comment: Is (s)he a math teacher? From the logic point of view, it is definitely true that there is a rock in front of your house. The claim is not saying "there is exactly one rock in front of your house", which would be false

Comment: This is really a question about good communication. If the other person understands what you mean, then the communication is successful. There are times when "one rock" means "only one rock", and there are times when it means "at least one rock". If the context is not clear, then use more words.

Comment: It's an ambiguous statement and depends *entirely* on how the speaker is defining language and arguments for either interpretation can be valid.  If "There are *n* rocks" means "the cardinality of the rocks is *n*" then your teacher is correct.  If it means "there exist two distinct rocks" then your are.  If I heard the statement by itself I'd interpret it as the teacher does, but if I heard this as part of the question as to whether "there is one rock" is true or false I'd interpret it as you did as I'd assume that is the point.  ... Just nod and say "I see"....

Comment: Same thing with the "how many months" puzzle: the question relies on deliberately misinforming the other person in order to appear clever. "To have" can mean "to contain", but it can also mean "to consist of". The answer could be $12$, or it could be $1$ (at least on non-leap-years). Or the answer could be that you use the ancient Mayan calendar, so obviously there are no months that long.

Comment: @Théophile:  I hadn't heard the "how many months" puzzle, but I'm guessing from context that it asks how many months have $28$ days

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes, it's a classic (and in my opinion, annoying) riddle; see the last line of the question above. Related: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: @Théophile Thank you for your comments. Interestingly enough, I came across the 12 months riddle in a book about mathematics. Here is the snippet: https://imgur.com/a/ZL8gK92

If you're interested, the book is called "How to Think Like a Mathematician: A Companion to Undergraduate Mathematics" by Kevin Houston

Comment: @MichaelYe The passage in that book is talking about how mathematicians are often perceived negatively by others, but also quotes the "mathematican's answer" to the riddle... I see a connection there. :) Imagine if I begged for money to feed my poor cat that has one leg. Even a mathematician would probably feel swindled after finding out that I just chose not to mention the other three. On a more serious note, this kind of thing happens all the time in politics and law, in much more convoluted ways. Finally, coming back to the original question:

Comment: (cont'd) In the English language, you would typically say "there is *one* rock in front of my house" when there is *only* one rock. If there is *at least* one, then you would say "there is *a* rock". Other languages don't have different words for "a" and "one", and make the distinction using other means.

Comment: The statement is literally true, but it violates [Grice’s maxim of quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle).